# Is it possible to create necessary / required interfaces?

Tags: java, security, interface

i have a little kont in my brain about structuring our code. We have a REST Backend based on SpringBoot. To handle requests regarding to security checks we use HandlerInterceptors. In some specific cases we need a specific interceptor and not our default one. The default one is registered in a 3rd party lib that no one can forget it. But i want all coders to think about this specific interceptor.
Actually, i just said it to them to achieve this.

Here's my question: Is there an option to create required (or necessary) interfaces which must be implemented? This would be a way to provide our security code by lib and to have the security that every coder implemented our specific interface (also if he just does nothing with it).

pseudo code:

```
public interface thinkForIt(){

Object SecBean specificSecBean;

public void methodToThinkOn();

}

public SecImpl implements thinkForIt(){

@Override
public void methodToThinkOn(){
return null; // i thought about it but i do not need to do anyting!

}
```

If the interface *thinkForIt* would have any annotations like @required, users could get warning or error if they did not implement it...

Looking for a solution and thanks for your comments in advance!

Comment: What is your specific reason for not using Spring Security?

Comment: History. The Project was not everytime builded with spring. But please don't mind spring too much, i can imagine diffrent cases where a neccesary interface could be helpful.

Comment: Please use proper typing, spelling, and capitalization. This site is meant to be more like Wikipedia, less like a casual chat room.

Comment: Surely it completely depends on how the class implementing the interface is loaded, no? Just having a class that implements an interface is completely useless if the class is never instantiated. So presumably you have some discovery mechanism which searches for classes that might implement the interface? (imagine Spring's component scan). The discovery mechanism is the place to enforce this constraint.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I just thougt about an option like this and i could find cases where i need it. Maybe the example above was not the best one, but it was one. Thanks for you reply.

Answer (score 0):

Your overall design is questionable; you are reinventing security code, which is always a red flag. Use Spring Security instead.

However, there's a simple way to ensure that "some bean of type `Foo`" has been registered with the context:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ContextConfigurationVerifier {
  final Foo required;
}
```

Comment: Finally thanks for your advice. I changed to spring security and mehtodexpressionevaluator. it is what we need. the problem of dictating the implementation to the dev team still exists, but that is what we have to accept. Using old code for new architecture was not that smart.